Volume of momentum space of an ideal gas
In An Introduction to Thermal Physics by Schroeder, while deriving the multiplicity of an ideal gas makes the following statements (image below):

Even in quantum mechanics, the number of allowed wavefunctions is infinite.
But the number of independent wavefunctions (in a technical sense that’s defined
in Appendix A) is finite, if the total available position space and momentum space
are limited. I like to picture it as in Figure 2.9. In this one-dimensional example,
the number of distinct position states is $L/\Delta x$, while the number of distinct momentum states is $L_p /\Delta p_x$ The total number of distinct states is the product,
$$\frac{L\,L_p}{\Delta x\,\Delta p_x}=\frac{L\,L_p}{h}$$
according to the uncertainty principle. In three dimensions, the lengths become
volumes and there are three factors of h:
$$\Omega=\frac{V\,V_p}{h^3}$$


Here we have an ideal monoatomic gas's single atom in a cuboidal box, whose momentum is constrained in the following manner
$$p^2_x+p^2_y+p^2_z=2mU$$
Where $m$ is its mass and $U$ is its kinetic energy.
Since this is the equation of a sphere, we can multiply by a small thickness $\Delta p_r$ to make it a volume.
Now the calculation for the momentum volume in Schroeder seems off to me, in that the volume here is a sphere rather than a cubical box, thus instead of using $\Delta p_x,\Delta p_y,\Delta p_y$, shouldn't $\Delta p_r,\Delta p_\theta,\Delta p_\phi$ (uncertainties in spherical coordinates) be used? this would alter the uncertainty products as well, making the overall constants a bit different.

The textbook does not assume such constraint, neither in 1D nor in 3D; instead, momentum in each three directions is supposed to be independently having any value from some interval $-L_p,L_p$, so many different energies are allowed. You are correct this is not a very physical assumption, as one isolated particle on a line segment or in a box should have constant kinetic energy.

However, when there are very many particles in the system, the constraint of constant energy of the system no longer limits any individual particle momentum, so the derivation is kind of right, the number of q. states associated with phase space element $VV_p$ is $VV_p/h^3$.
